# Error while reading multiple DOCX files in a Folder into multiple dataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

I am trying to write a code where I have to read multiple docx files and extract a particular table  from each of the docx file and create dataframes for each of them.
my code goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
directory = 'C:\\folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for document in files:
         if document.endswith('.docx'):
             table_num=4
             nheader=2
             table =document.tables[table_num-1]
             data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
             df = pd.DataFrame(data)
             df='df_' + document
             outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
             hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
             df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am getting the error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tables'

but I was able to run the same thing for single file as a function.

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import os
directory = 'C:\\folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4'

def read_docx_table(document,table_num=1,nheader=1):
    table =document.tables[table_num-1]
    data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    if nheader ==1:
        df=df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader == 2:
        outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
        hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
        df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    elif nheader>2:
        print("Not Working")
        df.DataFrame()
    return df


document = Document("file1.docx")
table_num=2
nheader=0
df = read_docx_table(document,table_num,nheader)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code below you have this line

```
document = Document("file1.docx")
```

so document is no longer a string with the filename.

In the other part you get the error because document is still a string

```
table = document.tables[table_num-1]
```

and a string doesn't have attribute tables.

Edit:
There is another line which will cause Error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = 'df_' + filename # <---- change df to a string
outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
```

you change df to a string and then try to use "iloc" on a string...won't work.